# Issue in preserving comments when merging 2 yamls using deepmerge python module and using ruamel.yaml

Tags: dictionary, merge, comments, ruamel.yaml

**Code:**

```
from deepmerge import always_merger
import ruamel.yaml

fileA = "source.yaml"
fileB = "dest.yaml"

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

with open(fileA,'r+') as f:
   fileAdictionary= yaml.load(f)

with open(fileB,'r+') as f:
   fileBdictionary = yaml.load(f)

result = always_merger.merge(fileAdictionary, fileBdictionary)
with open('output.yaml','w+') as f:
   yaml.dump(result,f)
```

**source.yaml**

```
element:
    connection:
        test: true
```

**dest.yaml**

```
element:
    connection:
        test: true
    networkPolicy:
        enabled: true
        # network policy has been enabled
    test_str_param: "abc"
    # comment for string parameter
    test_int_param: 10
    # comment for the integer parameter
    test_bool_param: true
    # comment for the boolean parameter
```

**Actual Output**

***output.yaml***

```
element:
  connection:
    test: true
  networkPolicy:
    enabled: true
        # network policy has been enabled
  test_str_param: abc
  test_int_param: 10
  test_bool_param: true
```

**Problem Description**

As you can see in the output.yaml, the comments for the elements `test_str_param`, `test_int_param` and `test_bool_param` is not preserved or carry forwarded from `dest.yaml`

**Expectation**

What needs to be done so that all the comments pertaining to all parameters are preserved in the final `output.yaml`

**Expected Output**

```
element:
    connection:
        test: true
    networkPolicy:
        enabled: true
        # network policy has been enabled
    test_str_param: "abc"
    # comment for string parameter
    test_int_param: 10
    # comment for the integer parameter
    test_bool_param: true
    # comment for the boolean parameter
```

Comment: your code was missing a closing parenthesis at the end, probably missed with copy-paste. You also did `import yaml` which was never used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you load from your input are `CommentedMap` instances and these are sub-classes
of `dict`.  `deepmerge` handles them as dicts, but since it doesn't do anything special
for the comments you lose them if keys are merged in an already existing
`CommentedMap` (like `fileAdictionary['element']`), but not when a value that is merged in
is a `CommentedMap` and doesn't exist in the `fileAdictionary` yet (i.e. there is no
`fileAdictionary['element']['networkPolicy']`)

`deepmerge` allows you to add your own strategies, but I am not sure what is
the best/recommended procedure to add new types:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
# from deepmerge import always_merger
import deepmerge
import ruamel.yaml
RYCM = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap

class CommentedMapStrategies(deepmerge.strategy.core.StrategyList):
    NAME = 'CommentedMap'

    @staticmethod
    def strategy_merge(config, path, base, nxt):
        for k, v in nxt.items():
            if k not in base:
                base[k] = v
            else:
                base[k] = config.value_strategy(path + [k], base[k], v)
        try:
            for k, v in nxt.ca.items.items():
                base.ca.items[k] = v
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    
        return base

    @staticmethod
    def strategy_override(config, path, base, nxt):
        """
        move all keys in nxt into base, overriding
        conflicts.
        """
        return nxt

# insert as it needs to be before 'dict'
deepmerge.DEFAULT_TYPE_SPECIFIC_MERGE_STRATEGIES.insert(0, (RYCM, 'merge'))
Merger = deepmerge.merger.Merger
Merger.PROVIDED_TYPE_STRATEGIES[RYCM] = CommentedMapStrategies

always_merger = Merger(deepmerge.DEFAULT_TYPE_SPECIFIC_MERGE_STRATEGIES, ['override'], ['override'])

fileA = Path('source.yaml')
fileB = Path('dest.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4)
result = always_merger.merge(yaml.load(fileA), yaml.load(fileB))
yaml.dump(result, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
element:
    connection:
        test: true
    networkPolicy:
        enabled: true
        # network policy has been enabled
    test_str_param: abc
    # comment for string parameter
    test_int_param: 10
    # comment for the integer parameter
    test_bool_param: true
    # comment for the boolean parameter
```

Depending on where you have comments in your YAML documents, you might have to amend/complete the
comment copying in `strategy_merge`.

Please note that the above relies on `CommentedMap` internals that might change,
so pin the `ruamel.yaml` version and test before upgrading it.

Comment: Thanks Anthon.. I am trying to use helm-docs which basically generates a md document based on the parameter and the comments, and it associates the comments that are before the parameter as description whereas in reality the comments are placed below the parameter using ruamel.yaml . How to deal with this.

Comment: The keys are ordered so you can find the key that precedes the one you are looking at. Something like `y = list(x.keys())`  and then `x.ca.items[y.index('c') - 1]`

Comment: Hi Anthon, I am struggling to fit the above comment in the code which you have mentioned. Where do i need to place the comment so that i  get the comments before the key.

Comment: I had not realiased you wanted that in this context, just that you wanted to access the comments for further processing. I guess you could build in something in `strategy_merge()` that would look at the preceding key of `nxt` and updates the comment on the key following the preceding key in `base`, that is not going to be trivial.

Comment: Sure Anthon.. Let me try it.. thanks a ton